# Objective-C int datatype in class gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, class

I am currently learning Objective-C. I have created a class to hold information about cars (BasicCar). Also created a child class to hold the car's color and amount of doors (ExtendedCar). All properties are text (`NSString`) except for the amount of doors, which is of type `int`.

My parent class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <cocoa/cocoa.h>

@interface BasicCar : NSObject {

NSString *make;
NSString *model;

}

@property (readwrite, retain) NSString* make;
@property (readwrite, retain) NSString* model;


@end

#import "BasicCar.h"

@implementation BasicCar

@synthesize make;
@synthesize model;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}


@end
```

My child class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <cocoa/cocoa.h>
#import "BasicCar.h"

@interface ExtendedCar : BasicCar {

NSString* color;
int doors;

}

@property (readwrite,retain) NSString* color;
@property (readwrite) int doors;

@end


#import "ExtendedCar.h"

@implementation ExtendedCar : BasicCar

@synthesize color;
@synthesize doors;


@end
```

My main code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BasicCar.h"
#import "ExtendedCar.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{


ExtendedCar *myCar1 = [[ExtendedCar alloc]init];
NSString *carMake = @"BMW";
NSString *carModel = @"M5";
NSString *carColor = @"blue";
int carDoors = 4;

[myCar1 setMake:carMake];
[myCar1 setModel:carModel];
[myCar1 setColor:carColor];
[myCar1 setDoors:carDoors];



ExtendedCar *myCar2 = [[ExtendedCar alloc]init];
carMake = @"Hummer";
carModel = @"H3";
carColor = @"green";
carDoors = 4;

[myCar2 setMake:carMake];
[myCar2 setModel:carModel];
[myCar2 setColor:carColor];
[myCar2 setDoors:carDoors];


NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %@ \n\n",[myCar1 make],[myCar1 model],[myCar1 color], [myCar1 doors]);

NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %@ \n\n",[myCar2 make],[myCar2 model], [myCar2 color], [myCar2 doors]);


return 0;
}
```

Now when I debug it, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in Xcode at this line:

```
NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %@ \n\n",[myCar1 make],[myCar1 model],[myCar1 color], [myCar1 doors]);
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this? It does not happen when I remove the 'doors' part, so it has to do something with the 'int' data.

Comment: Quit tip: be sure to use the correct format specifier when printing integers.  use %i instead of %@.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeremy said in a comment, you're using the wrong format specifier. `%@` is the format specifier for obj-c objects. This is correct for `make`, `model`, and `color`, but it's not correct for `doors` because that's a C primitive datatype (`int`). The correct format specifier for `int`s is `%i` (or `%d`).

```
NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %d \n\n",[myCar1 make],[myCar1 model],[myCar1 color], [myCar1 doors]);

NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %d \n\n",[myCar2 make],[myCar2 model], [myCar2 color], [myCar2 doors]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format `%@` is _only for outputting Objective C objects, not integers.

According to Apple's [String Format Specifier list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), the correct format to output an integer is `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %@ \n\n",[myCar1 make],[myCar1 model],[myCar1 color], [myCar1 doors]);
```

By

```
NSLog(@"Make: %@, Model: %@, Color: %@, Doors: %i \n\n",[myCar1 make],[myCar1 model],[myCar1 color], [myCar1 doors]);
```

The `%@` has been replaced by `%i` : you can find explanations about that here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html